# Using variants with font-awesome in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, font-awesome, variant

I'm new to Vue.js, and I'm trying to use variants to display information about a real estate property (like # of bedrooms, bathrooms, living area, parking, etc) in an unordered list, and what I'd like is to add an icon to it using font-awesome that displays accordingly.

I'm using Vue-CLI, and my main.js file looks like this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App";
import router from "./router";
import { library } from "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core";
import { faBed } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faBath } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome";

library.add(faBed, faBath);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.component("font-awesome-icon", FontAwesomeIcon);

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

So far, I'm able to make it work like this. Home.vue looks like:

```html
<ul class="container hero__list">
          <li
            class="hero__items"
            v-for="variant in variants"
            :key="variant.variantId"
          >
            <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fas', 'bed']" />
            {{ variant.variantTitle }}
            <span class="hero__result">{{ variant.variantResult }}</span>
          </li>
        </ul>

<script>
export default {
  name: "home",

  data() {
    return {
      heading: "56 Main Street",
      subheading: "Rethink The Way You Live. Discover Your Future",
      variants: [
        {
          variantId: 111,
          variantTitle: "Bedrooms",
          variantResult: 3
        },
        {
          variantId: 112,
          variantTitle: "Bathrooms",
          variantResult: 2
        },
        {
          variantId: 113,
          variantTitle: "Living Area",
          variantResult: 1850
        },
        {
          variantId: 114,
          variantTitle: "Parking",
          variantResult: 2
        }
      ]
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

But once I change the icon tag to a variant like this `<font-awesome-icon :icon="variantIcon"/>` and add it to each of my variants like this `variants: [
        {
          variantId: 111,
          variantTitle: "Bedrooms",
          variantResult: 3
          variantIcon: faBed
        },` it gives me the following error:

[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: faBed is not defined"

Is this possible to do?

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: Dan, is there a reason why you're putting the icon arguments as '['fa','bed']"? It should work with just "bed"

Comment: I found in this documentation that is better to be explicit: https://github.com/FortAwesome/vue-fontawesome, but I think you can add it both ways

Comment: Try 
```
import { faBed, faBath  } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
```

instead of the two separate statements and tell me what results you get

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had already tried that option as well with no luck. When I do that and create the variant for variantIcon and set it to bed or faBed, it makes my entire ul content disappear. It tells me that "[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: bed is not defined"

found in

---> <Home> at src/components/Home.vue
       <App> at src/App.vue
         <Root>"

Comment: Just in case this helps, this is what I'm trying to do: <font-awesome-icon :icon="variant.variantIcon" />
            {{ variant.variantTitle }} <span class="hero__result">{{ variant.variantResult }}</span> <script> data() { return { variants: [
        {
          variantId: 111,
          variantTitle: "Bedrooms",
          variantResult: 3
          // variantIcon: faBed
        },... I'll try to add this to codepen and update this comment since it looks messy on here